# How to capture exiting of Qt Application when shut down by debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, debugging, qt4, application-shutdown

I am developing a GUI application in Qt 4.8.4 with Visual Studio 2010. I need to perform some cleanup work before my application closes so I have reimplemented the QWidget closeEvent in my MainWindow class to capture when the user either clicks X or when they select File->Exit from the menu.  That works fine.  The problem however is when I am running the application in the VS debugger and I use the debugger to shut down the application the close event doesn't get triggered.  I can always just shutdown my application by clicking File->Exit or clicking X but sometimes I forget and shut down the debugger instead so it's really more of an annoyance.  Is there a way to capture when the debugger shuts down my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of.

The logic of it: the debugger is running a sandbox, and when it shuts down, the sandbox gets freed.  Your application is running inside that sandbox - so when that sandbox gets freed/closed/destroyed, your app simply vanishes without any cleanup.